# PrintWriter not working, but PrintStream is

Tags: output, printwriter, printstream

I'm trying to print some characters to an output file. If I do:

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt")));

out.println("Hi");

nothing happens.

However, if I do:
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("test.txt"));
out.println("Hi");

the appropriate message is printed and visible in the test.txt file. I'm wondering why this is happening??